# Fixing botched yum update: cannot remove duplicates

Tags: centos, centos7, yum, package-management

I was performing a routine `yum update` when it starting throwing a stream of 'non-fatal' errors. It was complaining the machine had run out of memory. Nevertheless, yum didn't find it necessary to stop this train.

So when it was done and I ran another `yum update` to check, it listed 100+ packages that are duplicates. Apparently, the memory shortage meant yum could not perform the removal of duplicates. After some searching, I found the `package-cleanup --cleandupes` command. This neatly listed the duplicates and offered to remove them. YES!

My delight was short-lived, when it errored out with:
`iptables = 1.4.21-34.el7 is needed by (installed) iptables-services-1.4.21-34.el7.x86_64`

While this is true, the duplicate it listed to be deleted was version 1.4.21-33.el7.

When manually trying: `rpm -e --justdb iptables-services-1.4.21-33.el7.x86_64` it says again:

`error: Failed dependencies:
        iptables = 1.4.21-34.el7 is needed by (installed) iptables-services-1.4.21-34.el7.x86_64`

It does not seem to understand I want to delete version '33', not '34'. How can I solve this?

Comment: If you try to simply update iptables, what does that give you?

Comment: It hits me with the list of duplicates and errors out. Before that, it tries to resolve dependencies and notes, rather contradictory: `Error: Package: iptables-services-1.4.21-33.el7.x86_64 (@base) Requires: iptables = 1.4.21-33.el7 Removing: iptables-1.4.21-33.el7.x86_64 (@base) Updated By: iptables-1.4.21-34.el7.x86_64 (base) Installed: iptables-services-1.4.21-33.el7.x86_64 (@base) Installed: iptables-services-1.4.21-34.el7.x86_64 (@base)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, trying out some more options to force the deletion of duplicates (which, by the way, the `rpm` command does not support, it only works for installing and updating packages), I came across the `--removenewestdupes` option for the `package-cleanup` command. This is, in fact, approaching the problem the other way around, by asking it to remove the *newer* rather than the older versions.

Issuing:
`package-cleanup --cleandupes --removenewestdupes`

...proceeded without errors. After that I could do `yum update` to properly update the older packages and everything was back on track again.